# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (flask python)

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify
from mysql import connector
from flask import request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask import render_template
from flask_login import LoginManager
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'many random bytes'

db = connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    passwd = '',
    database = 'rumahbuku'
)

if db.is_connected():
    print('Connection Successfull')



@app.route('/login/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        
        cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT * from login WHERE username = %s AND password = %s',
                (username, password))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        if user[0] == 'admin':
            session['loggedin'] = True
            message = 'Logged In Successfull'
            return redirect('/dashboard_kasir')
        else:
            message = 'Please Enter The Correct Username or Password'
    return render_template('login.html', message=message)
```

i want to make something for a project, if the username and the password correct it works but when the username and password wrong, it shows "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" this error and not showing my "else". it says the problem was from "if user[0]". can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you think is being returned if the username and password don't match?

Comment: add `print(user)` juste after retrieving it, you'll understand

Answer (score 0):

The error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" occurs when you try to access an attribute or element of an object that is None. In your code, this happens when the username and password don't match any record in the database, and the cursor.fetchone() method returns None.

To handle this situation, you should check whether the user variable is not None before attempting to access its elements. Here's an updated version of your code to address this issue:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for, session, render_template
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from mysql import connector

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your_secure_secret_key'  # Replace with a secure secret key

db = connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    database='rumahbuku'
)

if db.is_connected():
    print('Connection Successful')

@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = %s', (username,)
        )
        user = cursor.fetchone()

        if user is not None and check_password_hash(user[1], password):
            session['loggedin'] = True
            flash('Logged In Successfully', 'success')
            return redirect('/dashboard_kasir')
        else:
            flash('Incorrect Username or Password', 'danger')

    return render_template('login.html', message=message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In this modified version, I added the condition if user is not None before checking the password. This ensures that you only attempt to access user[1] if user is not None. This should prevent the "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error when the username and password are incorrect.